# How to remove specific words / spaces from a form

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently building a donation form with a WordPress plugin.

The only problem I'm facing is that I only want to display the price in the options like, '€ 3' '€ 5' '€ 10' 'Different', but the plugin adds a few words and spaces standard. I don't want to edit the code in the plugin itself, as this will be removed when the plugin updates.

This is the current HTML from the plugin :

```
<div class="donate-box"><ul id="form_624_field_2" label class required style="list-style-type:none;margin:0;"><li>
                        <label>
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    onchange="mollie_forms_recurring_methods_624();mollie_forms_624_totals();" 
                                    data-frequency="months" 
                                    data-freq="iedere maanden" 
                                    data-pricetype="fixed" 
                                    data-price="5.00" 
                                    data-vat="" 
                                    name="rfmp_priceoptions_624" 
                                    value="2"
                                     checked> 
                            / (&euro; 5,00 iedere maanden)
                        </label>
                      </li><li>
                        <label>
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    onchange="mollie_forms_recurring_methods_624();mollie_forms_624_totals();" 
                                    data-frequency="months" 
                                    data-freq="iedere maanden" 
                                    data-pricetype="fixed" 
                                    data-price="10.00" 
                                    data-vat="" 
                                    name="rfmp_priceoptions_624" 
                                    value="1"
                                    > 
                            / (&euro; 10,00 iedere maanden)
                        </label>
                      </li><li>
                        <label>
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    onchange="mollie_forms_recurring_methods_624();mollie_forms_624_totals();" 
                                    data-frequency="months" 
                                    data-freq="iedere maanden" 
                                    data-pricetype="fixed" 
                                    data-price="15.00" 
                                    data-vat="" 
                                    name="rfmp_priceoptions_624" 
                                    value="3"
                                    > 
                            / (&euro; 15,00 iedere maanden)
                        </label>
                      </li><li>
                        <label>
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    onchange="mollie_forms_recurring_methods_624();mollie_forms_624_totals();" 
                                    data-frequency="months" 
                                    data-freq="iedere maanden" 
                                    data-pricetype="open" 
                                    data-price="" 
                                    data-vat="" 
                                    name="rfmp_priceoptions_624" 
                                    value="4"
                                    > 
                            Different (iedere maanden)
                        </label>
                      </li></ul></div>
```

As you can see, the plugin automatically places the words "iedereen maanden" and "( )" inside the li with a lot of white spaces before and after. The last li is a option where the user can type in a custom price.

I already tried the JavaScript below, which works to remove the words / spaces, but when I try to test a donation the payment provider says that the price is too low (I guess the words also remove the value?).

```
$('.donate-box ul li').text(function (i,t) {
    return t.slice(0, -72);
});

$('.donate-box ul li').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.text( $th.text().substr(99) );
});
```